# Package input parameter SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a package in Oracle SQL Developer and want to have a public input parameter that another user can input a date to. I tried the following code -

```
Create PACKAGE Assignment_1_Pack is
 vstartDate date := to_date('&startDate', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
 vendDate date := to_date('endDAte', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

END;
```

When I try to run it I get the following message

```
Empty package Assignment_1_pack definition (no public members).
```

I was expecting the window that pops up to prompt for an input but I haven't used packages before so I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong

Comment: Stored PL/SQL like this isn't interactive and doesn't have substitution variables. Even if you got SQL Developer to prompt you, it would only prompt at compile time, then it would compile and store the code with `&startDate` and `&endDate` replaced with whatever literal values you typed in. It won't prompt users of the package.

Answer (score 0):

1. run `set define on;`
2. Use a command `create OR REPLACE package Assignment_1_Pack ...`

`SET DEFINE ON/OFF` toggles the substitution variables on or off. Probably the substitution of variables was turned off, so SQLDeveloper doesn't ask for the value
See this for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#sthref2736

> SET DEF[INE] {& | c | ON | OFF} Sets the character used to prefix
>   substitution variables to c.
>
> ON or OFF controls whether SQL*Plus will scan commands for
>   substitution variables and replace them with their values. ON changes
>   the value of c back to the default '&', not the most recently used
>   character. The setting of DEFINE to OFF overrides the setting of the
>   SCAN variable.

---

`create OR REPLACE package ...` prevents from errors in a case when the package has already been created. Simple `CREATE PACKAGE xxx` command fails if the package already exists. If you create the package for the first time, then all subsequent attempts will fail. `Create OR REPLACE ...` drops the package if it already exists, and then creates it again, so it newer fails.